# Rails: loop through and skip a specific object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looping through an array and showing the images:

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
    <%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(: thumb))%>
      <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachment),
                            data: { confirm: "Are you sure" },
                            :method => :delete %>
```

and this is what I have in the controller in order to find the attachments of the specific item:

```
@attachments = Attachment.where(item_id: @item.id)
```

The image column inside the attachments table is a `string`

I would like the loop to skip and not show a specific image I have stored inside the db, but show all the other images!

I have tried using the `break if` or `next if` condition but without any luck:

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
<% next if attachment.image == "no-image.jpg" %>
    <%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(:thumb))%>
      <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachment),
                            data: { confirm: "Are you sure" },
                            :method => :delete %>
```

or

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachment| %>
 <% break if attachment.image == "no-image.jpg" %>
    <%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(:thumb))%>
      <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachment),
                            data: { confirm: "Are you sure" },
                            :method => :delete %>
```

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

**Update 1**

this is what I'm getting in the console from `attachment.image`

`#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f8b932016f8 @model=#<Attachment id: 333, item_id: 136, account_id: nil, image: "no-image.jpg", created_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01", updated_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01">, @mounted_as=:image, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f8b93201540 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f8b932016f8 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f8b93200d48 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/public/uploads/attachment/image/333/no-image.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={:thumb=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70118693643120:0x007f8b93200c58 @model=#<Attachment id: 333, item_id: 136, account_id: nil, image: "no-image.jpg", created_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01", updated_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01">, @mounted_as=:image, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f8b932016f8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f8b93200b40 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70118693643120:0x007f8b93200c58 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f8b93200578 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/public/uploads/attachment/image/333/thumb_no-image.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>, :mini=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70118685692560:0x007f8b93200c30 @model=#<Attachment id: 333, item_id: 136, account_id: nil, image: "no-image.jpg", created_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01", updated_at: "2018-03-19 16:59:01">, @mounted_as=:image, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f8b932016f8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f8b932004b0 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70118685692560:0x007f8b93200c30 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f8b932034a8 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/public/uploads/attachment/image/333/mini_no-image.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>}>`

Comment: hey it seems like image is not a string. if it is string how does this line works`<%= image_tag(attachments.image.url(:thumb))%>`??

Comment: What does `attachment.image` return? Is it really just a string?

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for the reply... please check out the update in my question. I added what I get from `attachment.image`

Comment: @Dev obviously, it does **not** return `"no-image.jpg"` ;-)

Comment: Important info you mentioned in one of the comments: you are using carrierwave. To access the filename you have to write `attachment.image.original_filename` or `attachment.image.filename`.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't! @Stefan... so what name should I use then? any idea?

Comment: @Dev maybe you need to store the `image_name` in your model. And then do something like : `Attachment.where(item_id: @item.id).where.not(image_name: 'no-image.jpg')`

The thing is that : to filter your attachments it's better to pass by the `Model` and not doing this in the view.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the "reject" method.

```
<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image == "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| -%>
  ...
<% end -%>
```

edit:

Per comments below and above, the original poster is using Carrierwave to store files.  Because of this, "attachment.image" is a Carrierwave uploader object.

```
<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image.identifier == "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| -%>
  ...
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help @Michael Chaney... I did the following but thimage still shows up.. `<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image == "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| -%>
<%= image_tag(attachment.image.url(:mini))%>
<%= link_to t("store_item_edit_2"), remove_item_attachment_path(attachment),
                                data: { confirm: I18n.t("store_item_edit_3") },
                                :method => :delete %><% end -%>`

Comment: Not surprising since `attachment.image` isn't a string.  I'm just showing you how to do it based on what you originally posted, but obviously comparing that large object to a string isn't going to work.  It looks like you need to compare `attachment.image.original_filename` since you're using carrierwave.

Comment: Argh, don't use "original_filename", use "identifier".

Answer (score 3):

If you used paperclip you have default method to find file name **original_filename**

```
<% @attachments.each do |attachments| %>
     <% if attachment.image.original_filename != "no-image.jpg" %>
        <%= image_tag(attachments.image.url(:thumb))%>
          <%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_attachment_path(attachments),
                                data: { confirm: "Are you sure" },
                                :method => :delete %>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: okay, just find file name method for carrierwave, I think filename is default method

Comment: In carrierwave you can also use `original_filename`.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, this `<% if attachment.image.original_filename != "no-image.jpg" %>` return this `private method original_filename' called for #<AttachmentUploader:0x007fccc2587118>`

Comment: please use 'image_identifier' method, ex: attachment.image_identifier

Comment: Ow apparently `original_filename` is only available upon upload, afterwards you can use `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I go it to work with a combination of Michael Chaney and prasanthrubyist answers

`<% @attachments.reject { |attachment| attachment.image.file.identifier != "no-image.jpg" }.each do |attachment| -%>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also probably do this in the database via your original query. It's often best to try to keep this sort of logic out of the views.

```
@attachments = Attachment.where(item_id: @item.id).where.not(image: 'no-image.jpg')
```

Or if the database value is `nil`:

```
@attachments = Attachment.where(item_id: @item.id).where.not(image: nil)
```

I'd probably add it as a scope on the model so instead you can do something like:

```
@attachments = @item.attachments.with_image
```